# How to declare global variables with an input text file in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, scope

Say I have a variable `my_var` which I instantiate globally at the beginning of a script.
How can I modify its value using a `input.txt` file. Below is a minimal example of my problem.

This is the `input.txt` file:

```
my_var = 0.15 # Change the value
print(f"In the text file, my_var={my_var}")
```

This is the `test.py` python script:

```
my_var = 0.14
print(f"In the beginning, my_var={my_var}")

def run_exec():
    f = open("input.txt")
    lines = f.readlines()
    for l in lines:
        exec(l, globals(), locals())
    print(f"Within the function, my_var={my_var}")

run_exec()
print(f"Outside the function, my_var={my_var}")
```

Here is my output with Python3.8.5:

```
In the beginning, my_var=0.14
In the text file, my_var=0.15
Within the function, my_var=0.14
Outside the function, my_var=0.14
```

Answer (score 0):

`exec(l, globals(), locals())` is not doing what you think it is.

> exec(object[, globals[, locals]])
>
> This function supports dynamic execution of Python code. object must be either a string or a code object. If it is a string, the string is parsed as a suite of Python statements which is then executed (unless a syntax error occurs). 1 If it is a code object, it is simply executed.

If you were to open the Python interpreter and run `exec('0.15', globals(), locals())` you'd see it fails

Update your `run_exec()` function

```
def run_exec():
    f = open("input.txt")
    lines = f.readlines()
    for l in lines:
        global my_var
        my_var = l
    print(f"Within the function, my_var={my_var}")
```

or since your file only has one line if you wanted to get cute

```
def run_exec():
    global my_var
    my_var = open("input.txt").readlines()[0]
    print(f"Within the function, my_var={my_var}")
```

Which will give you

```
In the beginning, my_var=0.14
Within the function, my_var=0.15
Outside the function, my_var=0.15
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `l` is a `str` in the function `run_exec`. I need to execute the content of the string somehow.

Here is what I get when I use your function:

```
Within the function, my_var=my_var = 0.15 # Change the value
Outside the function, my_var=my_var = 0.15 # Change the value
```

I don't know how to globally change the content of the variable with the lines of my `input.txt` text file. Could you provide me with a minimum working example of your script please?